# Linearly independent columns of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to determing if the columns of A are linearly indepdent $\mathrm A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 &1 \\ 2 & -3 & 2 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 2 & 3\\ -3 & 2 & 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}$?

My solution:

I reduced this matrix to echelon form using gaussian elimination and produced

$$\text{ reduced}(A) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 &-1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Then in conclusion $x_4$ is a free variable so a nontrival solution of the system ax=0 may be obtained by substituting any nonzero for $x_4$ and backsolving for the other variables. Therefor the colums are linearly dependent.

Looking to get some guidance in this question on whether or not my workings are correct

Comment: well the last row of my matrix is all 0 so $x_4$ would be a free variable. I am just asking if my workings are correct. I was not sure if they were and if the answer was either the columns are independent or dependent

Comment: There is one eigenvalue 0, which has eigenvector $[1,0,-1,1]^T$, if you look carefully this satisfies each equation by your reduced matrix. So it seems reasonable. But you should not write $A=$ before as that is not true if the original matrix was A.

Comment: okay so are my workings incorrect then?

Comment: They seem correct. But it is wrong to write A= the new matrix if you have already decided the first matrix was the A matrix.

Comment: okay I see what you are saying there

Comment: I added the gaussian elimination information to the question and changed the $A=$ error. Please see so I didn't break anything.

Comment: looks good thanks for the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only used row operations in your reduction (which I didn't check) then the conclusion is that the 4th column is the difference between the 3rd and the 1st. So they are linearly dependent. Depending on the habbits of your instructor this may or may not be better than your answer (which is correct).

If you use column operations as well then dependence also follows from the last formula but you can not read off directly what the dependency is.

Comment: yes I used Gaussian elimination to get the echelon form

Comment: OK, your argument is fine then. It is equivalent to the conclusion I give but I think my formulation is closer to what is asked for. But it's mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: okay so I should include that the 4th column is the difference between the 3rd and the 1st just to be sure

Answer (score 0):

One way to determine if a set of vectors $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is linearly independent is to run Gram-Schmidt. If at any point in the Gram-Schmidt algorithm, you get the zero-vector, you know that the set is linearly dependent. If the algorithm terminates without any zero-vectors, you know that the set is linearly independent.

If you run Gram-Schmidt on the set of columns of your matrix, it will output the zero vector on the third step.

(Note: here's a good explanation of linear independence and Gram-Schmidt http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee103/lectures/linear-indep/linear-indep_slides.pdf)

Comment: okay then from your explanation I get that my answer is correct, thanks for another view on this problem